# W+E load segments are not allowed in Android game

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I've one Android project which is pretty old. compileSdk version is 23. now I'm upgrading it to API 28 but it gives `W+E load segments are not allowed` when I try to run.

Project is using share library called `libgba.so` shared lib built for `armeabi` actually the APK built on API 23 build SDK and same `armeabi` works on all device. The problem is only when I upgrade compileSdk even though if I use API 23 compilSdk version in Android studio it crashing with no log.

Comment: Did your `targetSdkVersion` also change? Behavior changes are usually tied to `targetSdkVersion`, and I'm not sure about the interaction between that and `compileSdkVersion`.

Comment: Yeah `targetSdkVersion` Changed to 28 from 21

Answer (score 0):

Segments aren't allowed to be both writable and executable since android-26: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md#writable-and-executable-segments-enforced-for-api-level-26

> Each segment in an ELF file has associated flags that tell the dynamic linker what permissions to give the corresponding page in memory. For security, data shouldn‘t be executable and code shouldn’t be writable. This means that the W (for Writable) and E (for Executable) flags should be mutually exclusive. This wasn't historically enforced, but is now.

It recommends using the following to diagnose the bad library:

```
$ readelf --program-headers -W libBadFlags.so | grep WE
  LOAD           0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x4c01d 0x4c01d RWE 0x1000
```

There's probably a linker script in the project that is causing the problematic segment to be generated with this, and it will need to be fixed to be either writable or executable, not both. This may mean that the app's code also needs to change to alter the segment's permissions as needed.